# iCloud Drive evicted files disappeared from mac Finder

Tags: icloud, finder

I am having a problem with my iCloud Drive synced files. I have created an Automator "Quick Action" to remove my iCloud Drive downloads so I could save some space on my Mac and eventually download them again once needed. This quick action uses `brctl evict` to remove the download of all files in a given folder and its subfolders. You can see the code in the image below.

[image: Automator Quick Action]

The problem I am having is that the evicted files have disappeared from my Documents folder. I can see all folders but not the files contained in them. All files appear when listing them through the Terminal. However, Finder does not show any. I have already tried restarting the Finder app, but the problem persists. Could someone help me with this issue?

[Update]

Adding some information asked in the comments:

OS version = macOS 14.0

Optimize Mac Storage = Enabled

iCloud > Desktop and Documents = Enabled

Comment: Please add 1) macOS version, 2) if you have Optimise Mac Storage enabled, and 3) do you have Store in iCloud > Desktop and Documents enabled.